# What's the difference between using widget and owl to develop a frontend element in odoo?

Tags: widget, odoo

I want to develop a search panel for my module. And odoo provides me with two ways. Which one should I choose? Is there anything I should notice?

Comment: Owl will probably be the only way in future. So use owl.

Comment: Does it mean that all the FE code will be refactored by OWL

Comment: That is only an assumption.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the search panel is not a widget but a view. And all widgets and views are ported to the owl. I think the new module knowledge has replaced the search panel.

Comment: Why do you think the knowledge module has replaced the search panel? @Paxmees